# Retrieve id of a given data Spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure in the database

```
Categorias_Produtos
- ID
---nome: Nome1
- ID 
---nome: Nome2
```

I'm displaying the data in a Spinner and capturing the name of the returned data. And it's okay.

But I'd like to capture the Id of this returned data, and I do not know how to do that?

Code:

```
mDatabaseCategorias = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Categorias_Produtos");

        mResultadoCat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvresultadoSpinnerCat);

        mDatabaseCategorias.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                List<String> categorias = new ArrayList<>();

                for( DataSnapshot categoriasSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){

                    String nomeCateg = categoriasSnapshot.child("nome").getValue(String.class);
                    categorias.add(nomeCateg);
                }


                //spiners resultado
                mSpinnerCateg = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCateg);
                ArrayAdapter<String> categoriasAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CadastroServico.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categorias);
                categoriasAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                mSpinnerCateg.setAdapter(categoriasAdapter);

                mSpinnerCateg.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        String resultado = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        mResultadoCat.setText(resultado);


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

From what I understand I would need to somehow send the item ID along with his name, to Spinner and from there retrieve that information.

I would like some ideas please !!

Comment: create a model. (constructors, setters/getters). query your firebase and add the query into a new list (as your model) and then when you select a name, its pulling it from a model...therefore you can get the id from it too. hopefully that makes sense

Comment: Yes it makes sense. But I do not know if I'll know how to do it. @DroiDev

Comment: ok I posted. I obviously didn't test it. it may to may not work. but that should get you started.

Comment: all you need is to override `ArrayAdapter#getItemId` method and return the id for given position

Comment: Sorry, did not I understand? @pskink

Comment: extend `ArrayAdapter` end override `getItemId` method - the docs say: `"Get the row id associated with the specified position in the list."`

Comment: Sorry, could you show me an example? @pskink

Comment: `@Override public long getItemId(int position) { return ids[position]; }`

Comment: Ok. Add within public void onItemSelected? For this is where I point the text and I would like to capture it, in the clicked item. @pskink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list.

```
List<SpinnerModel> list;
list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Query your firebase and add what you have into this list...into a new model.

```
list.add(new SpinnerModel(objectID, objectName));
```

Create a model.

```
public class SpinnerModel {
    String objectID;
    String objectName;

    public SpinnerModel(String objectID, String objectName){
        this.objectID = objectID;
        this.objectName = objectName;
    }

    create getters....
}
```

You can use the list and the getters to fill up your spinner. And then whatever you click, you can use the getObjectID to get the id.

Comment: Sorry I can not test now, but I fully understood the idea. Will that be visible in Spinner just the name? @DroiDev

Comment: yeah. create an adapter for the spinner and you can loop through your list and get the name out of it to display.... should be similar to a list view adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to store your ID duplicated under the root ID, this will simplify things for you when you want to retrieve data. DENORMALIZATION is the magic word for firebase or any JSON nosql database.

```
Categorias_Produtos
- 15
---nome: Nome1
---id: 15
- 16
---nome: Nome2
---id: 16
```